# how to update array of objects in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, updating

i have a state(array of object) which is as follows:

```
 const [state,setstate]=useState({picture:'',name:'',job:''})
```

and i have 3 inputs in Front-end side which get picture,name,job...
i define an array to save a collection of objects (consisting of picture,name and job of each person)  as follows:

```
 var colllection=[]
```

i use collection.push({state}) , but it overrides collection  and does not add new state to end of the mentioned array.any idea?

Comment: can you add the full code, please, otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: I have 2 ideas: 1) your `var collections` placed incorrectly and always reinitialized. 2) look at variable name - it contains 3 `l`

Comment: - just do it like this: collection.push({...state})

Comment: you were pushing object, which still referenced to state, so changing in state object, will override the old values in collection

Comment: `Do Not Modify State Directly` Please go through the documentation one. here; https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Answer (score 1):

For react state you need to replace the value rather than changing it.

So code something like this:

```
const [state, setstate] = useState([]);

const handleAddPerson = person => useState(prev => ([...prev, person]));
```

Where when we want to add a person we set the state to a new array that contains the contents of the original array plus the new object.

`useState` rather than being passed a new value can be passed a function which takes as an argument the previous value the state held and returns the new value for the state.

I'm used to syntactic sugar for creating a new array `[...prev, person]` this could be written in plain javascript as `prev.concat([person])`.